# Wordpressの記事の自動保存を無効化する方法

Tags: wordpress

お世話になります。
　試験的にWordpressでブログを作って、運用してみています。
　そこで、少し困ったことがあるので、質問させてください。
　新規投稿を追加した際、保存したりせずにF5キーを押すと、勝手に記事IDが1増えてしまいます。
　これを増えないようにする方法ってないのでしょうか。
　とりあえず、ざっと検索して、自動保存を無効化したらよいのかと思い、テーマディレクトリにある「functions.php」に下記記述を追加してみたりしたのですが、うまくいかないようです。

```
function autosave_stop(){
    wp_deregister_script("autosave");
}

add_action("wp_print_scripts", "autosave_stop");
```

何かよい方法があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。
　なお、Wordpressは5.1を利用しています。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 編集中に画像新規追加や、自動保存されても記事IDは増えるので、連続した記事IDにするには、カスタムフィールドなどに独自なIDを付加しなければ出来ません。（別ウインドウでカスタムpost,固定ページ,メディアなどの記事、画像を追加しても記事IDは増えます。）

Comment: お世話になります。返信が遅くなり、申し訳ありません。やはりそうですよね。了解しました。ありがとうございました。